# Мне нужно настроить позиционирование кнопки относительно модального окна

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Есть кнопка которая всплывает при клике на элемент , нужно чтоб она всегда всплывала в том месте как на рис.1[image: рис.1]

но если я выбираю другой элемент немного проскроллив , то она всплывает на том же месте как и на рис.1 [image: рис.2]

я пробовал делать через position fixed и sticky ничего не выходит , как можно решить  эту проблему?

вот код этого модального окна

```
        <div  class="modal-layout-choice">
         <div class="overlay">
           <div id="modal-layout-choice-id">
             <div class="modal-close">&times;</div>
             <button class="modal-layout-button ">выбрать</button>
             <div class="modal-layout-choice-content">
               <div class="modal-title-layout">Выберите планировку</div>
               <div class="modal-subtitle-layout">Мы подобрали наиболее актуальные на данный момент<br> планировки для лучшего заробатка</div>
```

после этого кода идет список с элементами планировки

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

div#modal-layout-choice-id
для этого элемента ставим position: relative

кнопка же, должна быть  position: absolute

но это в том случае, если кнопка находится вне скроллируемого блока

Answer (score 0):

Измените вложенность кнопки, я не могу сказать точно так как я не вижу ваш код. Но в целом при правильной вложенности кнопки `position fixed` должно помочь

Comment: я сейчас попробую , если не получится дополню вопрос кодом

Comment: добавил код в вопрос